# BizTalk: Mapping not executed when using unzip-component

Tags: biztalk, biztalk-2020

I am building an integration that should fetch a zip-file from SFTP and save it as XML on disk. I have got everything working except the unzip-part...

The integration looks like this.

1. Receive location polls the SFTP, and in the receive port "Inbound maps" I have provided a mapping schema (converting the txt-file in the zip file to XML).
2. Receive location:  polls the SFTP, custom receive pipeline.
3. Custom pipeline: In Disassemble first the unzip-component from BizTalk Utility pack ( [BizTalk Server 2020 – 20 days, 20 posts: Unzip File Pipeline Component for BizTalk Server 2020](https://blog.sandro-pereira.com/2020/04/03/biztalk-server-2020-20-days-20-posts-unzip-file-pipeline-component-for-biztalk-server-2020/)) and then the flat file disassembler. The document-schema here matches the source-schema in the mapping.
4. Send port: Save file on disk.

The problem is that when I run the integration, the file is picked up from the SFTP and the file is indeed unzipped but the send port saves the content from the original file to the send-location. It is as if the mapping is never executed.

But if I remove the unzip-component in the custom pipeline and manually unzip the file and upload the content (.txt-file) to the SFTP everything works fine.

As per Sandro Pereira's instruction no configuration is needed, so I don't really understand why it is not working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Receive Pipelines - Disassemble stage](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/biztalk/core/receive-pipelines#disassemble-stage) (Microsoft.com)

> If this stage contains more than one component, only the first component that recognizes the message format is run. If none of the components within the stage recognize the message format, the message processing fails.

So you can't have both in the disassemble stage of the pipeline and have them both execute.  Move the Unzip to the Decode stage of the pipeline.

Comment: Thanks for the link and the suggestion! Unfortunately I am not able to find any unzip components that I can use in the Decode stage (I just get a forbidden sign when I try to drag them to the Decode-stage). Can/should I use two pipelines instead?

Comment: @Hansel It should be possible to update the Pipeline component so that it can be put in the Decode stage, it is defined in the pipeline itself. Or ask Sandro if he can update it so it can run there as well.  Yes you could use two pipelines, but that means you would either have to drop the file to a file location to be picked up again, or run a pipeline from an Orchestration.